# Angularjs html5mode in Backand

Tags: angularjs, backand

Im using Backand to host an angularjs application. It worked fine, but now I want to enable html5mode, so that my URL's are SEO friendly.

In my angular app config file, I enabled this feature: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`, and in my index.html I added `<base href="/">`

When I navigate to the root, and change views from the app's navigation panel everything works fine, but when I reload the app from the borwser's refresh button I get 404.

From what I seen on other questions, I need to tell my server to serve your index.html file on all requests.

Is it possible to configure this on Backand ?

Comment: Yes its possible. But why do you want you to mix an SPA application with an backend application? Expecially routing comes with a lot of problems.

Comment: look for url rewrite rules for your web server..